# How do I handle .WIM image files?

Tags: software-recommendation, mount

I have an Asus netbook, and its recovery partition and recovery DVD have several images in [.WIM format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Imaging_Format).

Are there any Linux/Ubuntu tools to handle those images? Im looking for the equivalents of `dism`, `ImageX`, etc. But any tool (GUI or CLI) that could mount or extract or view its contents would be nice.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Gathering @fossfreedom 's and @Rinzwind 's ideas about 7z and Archive Manager, and tweaking with some of my own, I guess ive found a nice solution:

Archive Manager (actually File Roller) supports 7z (as long as p7zip package is installed), and 7z supports WIM (thanks guys!). But here is the catch: File Roller does not know that 7z supports WIM. So the trick consists in "fooling" File Roller to think WIM files are actually 7z. Sure, renaming (or appending) WIM filenames with ".7z" extension works. But it can be more elegant than that.

Ive downloaded and and examined File Roller's source code, and found out that it (thankfully) detects files by **mime types**, *not* filenames.

So the complete solution could be:

- Make sure you have [p7zip](http://p7zip.sourceforge.net/) package installed. You can install it with the following command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
  ```
- For Mime-Type dababase editing, install [assoGiate (File Types Editor)](http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2009/11/19/create-your-own-file-types-in-ubuntu-with-assogiate/). Its a very easy, intuitve, well-polished tool. A must-have for mime-type editing. Saved me more than once, including now
- To install it in Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise), use the following command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install assogiate
  ```
- To install it in Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty), you need to install libgnome-vfsmm-2.6-1c2a manually at [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/libgnome-vfsmm-2.6-1c2a). In "Published versions", click on the release of your architecture. In the next page, download the *.deb file in "Downloadable files". We need to install libxml++2.6-2 available in Universe repo too, so we can install assoGiate using dpkg:

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i libgnome-vfsmm-2.6-1c2a_2.26.0-1build1_amd64.deb
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install libxml++2.6-2
  sudo dpkg -i assogiate_0.2.1-3_amd64.deb
  ```
- Open it in `Menu > System Tools > File Type Editor`
- At it, go to `Type > Find` (CTRL+F, or search icon), type "7z".

[image: assogiate1]

- Select **x-7z-compressed**,  go to `Type > Edit`
- Go to `Filenames` tab, click on `Add` button
- Type ***.wim**, click `Add`

[image: assogiate2]

- Close all dialogs, and presto!
- Nautilus now show the WIM archives as a 7-zip archive. Which, given that is 7-zip that handles them, it is not entirely false. No renaming needed, filenames are intact.

[image: assogiate4]

- Double-click them, and good ol' Archive Manager opens them with no complains. No need of wine or any weird GUI

[image]

**Note**: these changes in the mime-type database are valid for the current user only. For a system-wide change, open File Type Editor as root:

```
gksudo assogiate &
```

Last but not least, for command line, all these steps can be skipped, and the following can be used:

```
7z x INPUTFILE.wim -oOUTPUTFOLDER
```

Answer (score 7):

EDIT: From comments received, Archive Manager should in theory have WIM support.  However for me trying to open a WIM gives a "Archive Type is not supported" error message.   However, copying the WIM to my desktop and added a .7z extension allows Archive Manager to open the WIM directly.  N.B. you need to install the 7Zip from the software center.

P7Zip has the ability to read WIM files.  If you search for "7Zip" in software center, it will install the command line tool "7z"

use 7z --help for the options.

An example from my Windows 7 Recovery disc is as follows:

```
7z e /media/Recovery3/Patch/Modules/Acer-HQ1/SET/WinRE\ LP\ Setup/MOD01SET74EN0N0006.WIM 1.xml

7-Zip 9.04 beta  Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Igor Pavlov  2009-05-30
p7zip Version 9.04 (locale=en_GB.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,4 CPUs)

Processing archive: /media/Recovery3/Patch/Modules/Acer-HQ1/SET/WinRE LP Setup/MOD01SET74EN0N0006.WIM[enter link description here][1]

Extracting  1.xml

Everything is Ok

Size:       1386
Compressed: 265513728
```

the .exe from the download site (link above) installs OK under wine (I'm using wine 1.3) - so you can browse the wim using a GUI:

[image]

Googling around, a native linux GUI is in short supply - [here](http://code.google.com/p/k7z/) is one I've found, but I haven't tested this one myself

[image]

Comment: The archive manager also supports 7zip.

Comment: @nickguletskii - I initially tried using that on my Windows 7 WIM  - it threw an error when I tried to right click and "open with archive manager"

Comment: @nickguletskii: I got same error as @fossfreedom when using Archive Manager to open WIM files. Its says "Archive type not supported."

Comment: @MestreLion you need 7zip installed and then you can use archive manager ;) same goes for rar: install unrar and archive manager can unrar.

Comment: @Rinzwind - curious - I've got 7zip installed but archive manager doesnt work with my windows 7 wim's.  Maybe works only with some older wim's.

Comment: hmm strange. I've seen it work (but not in natty though).

Comment: @Rinzwind and @MestreLion - found a solution for Natty!  See my edit.

Comment: @Rinzwind and @fossfreedom: Ive had 7z installed already... its my main compression tool since windows, log before i use Linux, and one of the first packages i installed. And it still does not run... well, at least not without a tweak. Gathering all info from you guys and some more researching, i was able to find a solution that, IMHO, is ubber-neat. Oh, btw: the renaming to ".7z" worked ;)

Comment: command line with 7z working for me, Ark doesn't report any error but displays empty window, thanks

Answer (score 6):

Anyone also must look to:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/wimlib/

From home page:

```
*wimlib-imagex* may be used to create customized images of Windows PE,
or to back up, install, or restore Windows operating systems.
```

Comment: The included `wimmount` program can also be used to mount .wim files read-only using FUSE. (For read-write, use `wimmountrw`).

Comment: The `wimtools` package looks similar to me, haven't looked into the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I wish a regular mount could do that job , some tracks using fuse

http://code.google.com/p/fuse-zip/issues/detail?id=13

-- 
http://rzr.online.fr/q/mount

Comment: It can't be mounted in a regular way because WIM files are just archives (a collection of files like ZIP, TAR, RAR), they lack a filesystem. That makes it plataform-indepedent, but also prevents themfrom being directly mounted (as filesystem images like ISO)

Comment: fuse is just for that ... if it can mount ssh it can mount anything :)

Comment: This might be true for readonly mounts (since read operations can be translated in almost any way) but for write operations, archive files miss several crucial features. For example, fragmented files. What happens when I replace a 8kB file within a mounted .zip archive with a 10kB file? In the worst case the archive needs to be completely recreated - especially if it is a "solid" one (like 7z or RAR do) and this can be very slow.

Comment: but it could work ... sometime performance is not a problem ...